# ASP VB.NET - FindControl isn't finding my control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, findcontrol

A little background. There is a masterpage as well. Here is the ASPX code

```
<asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStepOrder" runat="server" StepType="Step">
<div>
<p>
Please review the items below and enter the quantity of each item for which you are requesting credit.
</p>
<asp:Label ID="InvoiceItemsInstructionsLabel" runat="server" />
</div>
<div style="padding: 0;">
<asp:GridView ID="InvoiceItemsGridView" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Make" HeaderText="Make" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="PartNumber" HeaderText="Part Number" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Ordered" HeaderText="Ordered" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Shipped" HeaderText="Shipped" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Credit Code">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCreditCode" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
<asp:ListItem Text="--Select Value--" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Also my vb behind code

```
Dim ddlCreditCode As DropDownList = DirectCast(Me.WizardStepOrder.FindControl("ddlCreditCode"), DropDownList)
Dim sql As String
Dim cnn As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
sql = String.Format("select CreditCode, CreditCodeDescription from myDatabase..CreditCodes")
cnn = DBConnection.GetNamedConnection(NamedConnection.myDatabase)
cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, cnn)
Try
cnn.Open()
ddlCreditCode.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
ddlCreditCode.DataTextField = "CreditCodeDescription"
ddlCreditCode.DataValueField = "CreditCode"
ddlCreditCode.DataBind()
Catch ex As Exception
Throw ex
Finally
cnn.Close()
cnn.Dispose()
End Try
```

ddlCreditCode is coming back as nothing. why? I am trying to populate a dropdown list on my asp page with values from the database. But in order to do that, I need to be able to find that control. I read about an issue being that since there is a masterpage, i have to use contentplaceholder and use findcontrol on that and then use findcontrol on that placeholder, but that doesn't work either. I am thinking it has to do with either itemtemplate or the gridview. Do I have to loop through the gridview or something?

Comment: Is `row` a `GridViewRow`? If so, how do you get it? Also, where is the code located at all?

Comment: yes row is a gridviewrow. sorry, i forgot to include my foreach statement right above. I believe the reason it cannot find the id property because it is inside an itemtemplate?

Answer (score 0):

You dont do it.Change your code like this

```
Try
//prevent issue on connection already open for some reason
if cnn.state=Closed then cnn.open
//declare a sqldataadpter
dim da as SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
//declare Dataset
dim ds as new Dataset
//fill dataset
da.Fill(ds)
ddlCreditCode.DataSource =ds.table(0)
ddlCreditCode.DataTextField = "CreditCodeDescription"
ddlCreditCode.DataValueField = "CreditCode"
ddlCreditCode.DataBind()
Catch ex As Exception
Throw ex
Finally
cnn.Close()
cnn.Dispose()
```

Also i personally invite use o use Using statement with take care to destroy references themeself :)

if it work mark your answer as answered

Comment: the problem is that findcontrol isn't working to find my dropdownlist. that is the main issue i am having.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your code if `ddlCreditCode` is a child or sibling of `WizardStepOrder` (no closing tag). If it is not a direct child, `Me.WizardStepOrder.FindControl()` will not find it. Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> This method will find a control only if the control is directly contained by the specified container; that is, the method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the RowDataBound event to populate controls within your GridView

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

   If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then

     'Find the DropDownList in the Row
     Dim ddlCreditCode As DropDownList = CType(e.Row.FindControl("ddlCreditCode"), DropDownList)
     ddlCreditCode.DataSource =ds.table(0)
     ddlCreditCode.DataTextField = "CreditCodeDescription"
     ddlCreditCode.DataValueField = "CreditCode"
     ddlCreditCode.DataBind()


   End If
End Sub
```